# Resized Azure VM based on the Linux Docker+Rethinkdb image and the data was lost, is this to be expected?

Tags: linux, azure, docker, rethinkdb, azure-virtual-machine

Had about 20 documents in one Rethinkdb Database [Docker-based] on a Standard A1 and wasn't using it much so I decided to downsize it to Standard A0, after a few minutes the Rethinkdb server came back online completely empty (with only the test db)

The data was purely for test so no issue there, but is it expected to if someone upgrades a Linux + Docker + [container, Rethinkdb in this case] to lose data? Are there any steps to prevent that?

Comment: Do you use the official rethinkdb image (https://hub.docker.com/_/rethinkdb/) or a custom one? Does your rethinkdb container use a volume for storing persistent data? A bind-mounted directory?

Comment: The one that is in the Azure catalog, unsure if it is the official (but likely is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux systems on Azure have a local disk that is mounted as `/mnt` anything stored on this drive will be erased upon reboot. You can use this disk for caching and where temporary processing is required, but you should avoid storing anything that might be needed.

The best solution is to mount a data disk to the machine and use that as a volume to store data on.

This is also true of the D: drive on Azure Windows VMs

Comment: Correct, about the temp disk - safe to assume any/all data will be lost when resizing. Just a tiny clarification though: Data doesn't get erased on reboot, and will usually survive reboots (though there's always a chance of losing data at any time on a non-durable temporary disk).

Comment: @DavidMakogon it was an intentional omission, I always find its safer to say it won't last a reboot, than to say it *might* survive (which it isn't guaranteed to do)

Comment: Thank you guys, absolutely makes sense